# Forgot to add --purge to autoremove. Will there be any residues?

Tags: apt

I purged a package: **sudo apt purge pkg**

Then I ran autoremove: **sudo apt autoremove**

and it deleted a package that depended on pkg...but I forgot to add **--purge** to **autoremove**....Are there gonna be any residues as a result of this ? or am I ok ?

Comment: --purge will also remove any settings files in /etc. That's the ONLY additional step --purge does.

Comment: Purge removes a package completely.  Autoremove removes unneeded packages(hopefully that is all).

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it again by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

and also check the packages with residual configuration files and remove them by

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}')
```

---

For details see [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html), [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) and [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html).